# Scale items with iCarousel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, icarousel, scaletransform

I was trying to use iCarousel for one my solutions, I need to achieve something like the image below [image]

It should be exactly the way

`iCarouselOptionFadeMin` `iCarouselOptionFadeMax` `iCarouselOptionFadeRange` `iCarouselOptionFadeMinAlpha` works using

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
```

I tried to create a function exactly like

```
- (CGFloat)alphaForItemWithOffset:(CGFloat)offset
```

I discovered that it cane be done using `offset` values, but things are not working me, can any one can help me achieving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do this via the `iCarousel`'s `iCarouselTypeCustom` type in the delegate method

```
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform
```

Just set the type of the carousel (e.g. in `viewDidLoad` of the carousel's view controller):

```
self.carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCustom;
```

And calculate the transform as you like. I've laid the objects on a hyperbola, and shrink them in addition a bit as they move away from the center. That quite resembles your image, I think:

```
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform
{
    const CGFloat offsetFactor = [self carousel:carousel valueForOption:iCarouselOptionSpacing withDefault:1.0f]*carousel.itemWidth;

    //The larger these values, as the items move away from the center ...

    //... the faster they move to the back
    const CGFloat zFactor = 150.0f;

    //... the faster they move to the bottom of the screen
    const CGFloat normalFactor = 50.0f;

    //... the faster they shrink
    const CGFloat shrinkFactor = 3.0f;

    //hyperbola
    CGFloat f = sqrtf(offset*offset+1)-1;

    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, offset*offsetFactor, f*normalFactor, f*(-zFactor));
    transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 1/(f/shrinkFactor+1.0f), 1/(f/shrinkFactor+1.0f), 1.0);
    return transform;
}
```

and the result:
[image: result]

you can adjust the float constants to your liking.

For moving items around a circle while scaling them just use goniometric functions for translation, then rotate and scale:

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    if (option == iCarouselOptionSpacing)
    {
        return value * 2.0f;
    }
    if(option == iCarouselOptionVisibleItems)
    {
        return 11;
    }
    if(option == iCarouselOptionWrap) return YES;
    return value;
}

- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform
{
    const CGFloat radius = [self carousel:carousel valueForOption:iCarouselOptionRadius withDefault:200.0];
    const CGFloat offsetFactor = [self carousel:carousel valueForOption:iCarouselOptionSpacing withDefault:1.0f]*carousel.itemWidth;
    const CGFloat angle = offset*offsetFactor/radius;

    //... the faster they shrink
    const CGFloat shrinkFactor = 2.0f;
    //hyperbola (now only for shrinking purposes)
    CGFloat f = sqrtf(offset*offset+1)-1;


    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, radius*sinf(angle), radius*(1-cosf(angle)), 0.0);
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 0, 1);
    transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 1/(f*shrinkFactor+1.0f), 1/(f*shrinkFactor+1.0f), 1.0);
    return transform;
}
```

and again, the result:
[image: result2]

you can adjust the spacing and the radius in the `carousel:valueForOption:withDefault:` method.

Enjoy! :)

Comment: I was trying something different to what is in here. and your solution perfectly worked for me. I got my desired result.

Comment: Hi, suppose I want to make it a vertical hyperbola, how would I go about doing it? Thanks!

Comment: the iCarousel has a property `vertical` which sets the direction of the scroll gestures. Furthermore you need to switch the `x` and `y` parameters in `CATransform3DTranslate` to move the items alongside the y axis instead.

Answer (score 3):

A little modified and in **SWIFT** to copy paste ;) - works perfekt for me

```
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, valueForOption option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    if option == iCarouselOption.Spacing {
        return value * 1.8
    }
    return value
}

func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, itemTransformForOffset offset: CGFloat, baseTransform transform: CATransform3D) -> CATransform3D {
    let offsetFactor = self.carousel(carousel, valueForOption: iCarouselOption.Spacing, withDefault: 1) * carousel.itemWidth

    let zFactor: CGFloat = 150
    let normalFactor: CGFloat = 0
    let shrinkFactor: CGFloat = 1
    let f = sqrt(offset*offset+1)-1

    var transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, offset*offsetFactor, f*normalFactor, f*(-zFactor));
    transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 1/(f/shrinkFactor+1), 1/(f/shrinkFactor+1), 1);
    return transform;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment so i have to ask a further question as a reply :(

@burax is it possible to layout items on linear line instead of a hyperbola but keep the resizing?

Regards, and sorry for asking like this

Edit : with random tries i achieved with this :

```
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform
{
const CGFloat radius = [self carousel:carousel valueForOption:iCarouselOptionRadius withDefault:5050.0];
const CGFloat offsetFactor = [self carousel:carousel valueForOption:iCarouselOptionSpacing withDefault:0.8f]*carousel.itemWidth;
const CGFloat angle = offset*offsetFactor/radius;

//... the faster they shrink
const CGFloat shrinkFactor = 2.0f;
//hyperbola (now only for shrinking purposes)
CGFloat f = sqrtf(offset*offset+1)-1;


transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, radius*sinf(angle), radius*(1-cosf(angle)), 0.0);
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 0, 1);
transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 1/(f*shrinkFactor+1.0f), 1/(f*shrinkFactor+1.0f), 1.0);
return transform;
}
```

there is probably a better way but i am new to transformations :)

Comment: Basically you need to keep only the CATransform3DScale + have the CATransform3DTranslate move the items by `offset` in its X parameter. Alternatively, checkout my other answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178267/mac-dock-like-magnification-for-ipad/19569605#19569605