# UICollectionView issue (like carousel)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, icarousel

I need UICollectionView with 3 visible elements (the element in the middle is bigger). Like this

[image]

I'm trying to use https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel control, but there in Linear type all items has the same size and in Rotary type I can see other views behind. Is it possible to customize this control as I need or maybe better solution will be use another one good control, thanks!

Comment: Actually, I found a solution in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514041/scale-items-with-icarousel