# Scale items with iCarousel iCarouselTypeLinear mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, icarousel

I have an iCarousel and I want to make the center item larger than others. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514041/scale-items-with-icarousel) that gives the answer, the only problem is that the are not in line, but in circular way, how can I put the items one after the other like this (iCarouselTypeLinear):

[image: carousel]

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the code from the above link. Take a look at the [CATransform functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/index.html).

```
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform
{
    const CGFloat offsetFactor = [self carousel:carousel valueForOption:iCarouselOptionSpacing withDefault:1.0f]*carousel.itemWidth;

    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, offset*offsetFactor, 0, 0));
    return transform;
}
```

Comment: @YossiTsafar did you set `self.carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCustom;`?

Comment: do you have a github project I could look at?