# Scaling Images using iCarousel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, icarousel, scaletransform

I am using iCarousel for one of my solutions, I need to achieve something like the image below [image]

can any one can help me achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hope this helps you :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514041/scale-items-with-icarousel

Comment: sujania !! Thanks for ur comment but the requirement is different

Comment: Anybody there to help me on this!! Please