# How to set different page sizes in Android viewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, icarousel

I am trying to implement android vertical viewpager with multiple pages. Problem I am facing is I am unable to get the position of the page before they are visible.

Is there a way to transform page before it is visible/selected ? I tried OnResume, OnViewCreated and the page width is 0 and height is 0 before it is visible.

I was able to successfully apply TransformPage after selecting the view.

Is there a way to apply different height and width to each page size?

I am trying to implement something like below for Android.

[Mac Dock like magnification for iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178267/mac-dock-like-magnification-for-ipad)

Any help is appreciated.